# For kennel cough, how soon after symptoms disappear is it safe to be around other dogs?

Tags: dogs, health

I'm pretty sure my dog has kennel cough—she's had a hacking cough for a couple days and her daycare said it's been going around. We're isolating her from other dogs, but we also have a trip coming up soon and had planned on boarding her.

All the sources on kennel cough I've found say it'll likely resolve [within a week or two](https://www.akc.org/expert-advice/health/kennel-cough-symptoms-treatment-and-prevention/), that's a fairly large range. How soon after she stops displaying symptoms is it safe for other dogs to be exposed to her?

Comment: Did you saw a vet with your dog? Or called one?

Comment: I'd very much recommend checking with a vet to confirm. I've had my dog pick up some particularly nasty illnesses when boarded - and you don't really want a sick pet passing on their illnesses to other pets, or a recovering one getting hit by another one while recovering

Answer (score 1):

As Kennel Cough is highly contagious to other dogs, it is advised that you keep your dog away from other dogs for around two weeks, but this can vary depending on the severity of the infection. Generally, dogs recover completely within three weeks, although can be longer in older dogs, puppies, or sick patients.